# Cherrypy behing apache with mod_python

Tags: python, apache, cherrypy, mod-python

I have problem with cherrypy deployment behind apache with mod_python.

I have this apache configuration:

```
    4 <VirtualHost *>
  5         ServerAdmin martin@podhola.com
  6         ServerName pyth.madphoto.eu
  7         DocumentRoot /development/webadmin-interface/
  8         # Indexes + Directory Root.
  9         <Location />
 10                 PythonPath "sys.path+['/development/webadmin-interface']"
 11                 SetHandler python-program
 12                 PythonHandler cherrypy._cpmodpy::handler
 13                 PythonOption cherrypy.setup main::start
 14                 PythonDebug On
 15         </Location>
 16
 17         # Logfiles
 18         ErrorLog  /www/madphoto.eu/pyth/logs/error.log
 19         CustomLog /www/madphoto.eu/pyth/logs/ccess.log combined
 20 </VirtualHost>
```

and this cherrypy code to start the entire website

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
  2 # -*- coding: utf8 -*-
  3
  4 import os.path
  5 import cherrypy
  6 from mako.template import Template
  7 from mako.lookup import TemplateLookup
  8 from mako import exceptions
  9 from mako.exceptions import RichTraceback
 10 from ReadFromDB import *
 11 from DeleteFromDB import *
 12 from InsertToDB import *
 13 from BasePage import BasePage
 14 from ModifyEntryDB import *
 15 #from cherrypy.process.plugins import Daemonizer
 16 #from cherrypy import Application
 17
 18 current_dir = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
 19 mainlookup = TemplateLookup(directories=['./templates'], output_encoding='utf-8', input_encoding='utf-8', en    coding_errors='replace', format_exceptions = True)
 20
 21 class Main(BasePage):
 22         readfromdb = ReadFromDB()
 23         deletefromdb = DeleteFromDB()
 24         inserttodb = InsertToDB()
 25         modifyentrydb = ModifyEntryDB()
 26
 27         def index(self):
 28                 try:
 29                         mIndextemplate = mainlookup.get_template("main_index.txt")
 30                         return mIndextemplate.render()
 31                 except:
 32
 33                         traceback = RichTraceback()
 34                         for (filename, lineno, function, line) in traceback.traceback:
 35                                 print "File %s, line %s, in %s" % (filename, lineno, function)
 36                                 print line, "\n"
 37                         print "%s: %s" % (str(traceback.error.__class__.__name__), traceback.error)
 38
 39         index.exposed = True
 40
 41 #config = {
 42 #        '/bootstrap/css':{
 43 #                'tools.staticdir.on': True,
 44 #                'tools.staticdir.dir': os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'static'))
 45 #        }
 46 #}
 47 def start():
 48         cherrypy.tree.mount(Main(),config="/development/webadmin-interface/webadmin.conf")
 49         cherrypy.engine.start()
 50
 51
 52
 53 #cherrypy.quickstart(Main(), "/", "webadmin.conf")
```

and then first refresh of the site is doing 403 forbidden, and the second time I get in apache error log

```
[21/May/2013:11:48:38] MOD_PYTHON Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6/cherrypy/_cpmodpy.py", line 139, in handler
    setup(req)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6/cherrypy/_cpmodpy.py", line 84, in setup
    func()
  File "/development/webadmin-interface/main.py", line 49, in start
    cherrypy.engine.start()
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6/cherrypy/process/wspbus.py", line 184, in start
    self.publish('start')
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6/cherrypy/process/wspbus.py", line 147, in publish
    output.append(listener(*args, **kwargs))
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6/cherrypy/_cpserver.py", line 90, in start
    ServerAdapter.start(self)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6/cherrypy/process/servers.py", line 53, in start
    wait_for_free_port(*self.bind_addr)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6/cherrypy/process/servers.py", line 251, in wait_for_free_port
    raise IOError("Port %r not free on %r" % (port, host))
IOError: Port 8080 not free on '127.0.0.1'
```

But it is not working, it is followed by many manuals (I try different settings but still it is not working)

I have Debian squeeze server, cherrypy 3.1.2-1, apache2.

In standalone startup built-in server of cherrypy it works perfectly.

Please can You help? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You are starting the cherrypy server along with apache, the start function will only configure and mount the application but do not start the server, it should look like this:

```
def start():
    cherrypy.tree.mount(Main(),
                        config="/development/webadmin-interface/webadmin.conf")
```

The module `_cpmodpy` have more information easily readable with:

```
 python -m pydoc cherrypy._cpmodpy
```

As a general recommendation you should consider to use mod_wsgi, mod_python is unmaintained and considered deprecated in favor of mod_wsgi.

Comment: Thank You cyraxjoe, this fixed my problem with multilple starts, but now I see only white page (absolutely empty data) from server with no errors in apache log (local for virtual host and global) and I dont know why :(

Comment: --- UPDATE - when I try with telnet to send a HEAD request, I receive 400 error and with GET / I receve a binary trash with ending ���Wߟ7��Connection closed by foreign host.

Comment: Problem solved, thanks so much, this problem is with path in system, cherrypy and mako couldnt find a template path, I used full absolute path and now its okay.

Comment: Awesome @Mlocik!, then it will be a good thing if you mark this question as resolved.